# Wordpress same custom post template for different languages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress webpage where a former web developer created a custom post type using Pods pulgin, on this custom post type there is a post that we can call "Ejemplo", that post uses `content-single-ejemplo.php` to be build but the english version "Example" is being created with `content-single.php`.

**What should I do to use the same `content-single-example.php` for the same post on both languages** instead of `content-single.php` for the english version?
(We are using the plugin WPML for translations)

I've already tried cloning the `content-single-ejemplo.php` and rename it as `content-single-example.php` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content-single.php` or `content-single-post_type.php` are NOT part of the regular [Wordpress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) nor a [post template file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files/). In your case it's probably a custom [template part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/). Meaning that it as no default fallback nor redundancies and as no ties to the Wordpress core functionalities.

A template part is loaded on the front-end via the handy function `get_template_part`.

> Loads a template part into a template. Provides a simple mechanism for child themes to overload reusable sections of code in the theme. Includes the named template part for a theme or if a name is specified then a specialised part will be included. If the theme contains no `{slug}.php` file then no template will be included.
> The template is included using require, not `require_once`, so you may include the same template part multiple times.
> For the `$name` parameter, if the file is called "`{slug}-special.php`" then specify "special".

*- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/*

**In short, the content from a template part is just a reusable piece of code.**

Currently both of them (`content-single.php` and `content-single-ejemplo.php`) are ALREADY using the same end-file, which is probably `single.php` and I'm guessing that `content-single.php` and `content-single-ejemplo.php` are just loops, one for each language.

If you want somebody to be able to help you, you should include the content from both file, `content-single.php` and `content-single-ejemplo.php` and the parent file, which is probably `single.php`.

---

### Learn more

- [Visual Overview Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png)